# cannot import name 'StochasticFrontier' from 'frontier' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/frontier/__init__.py)

Tags: python, installation, pip, data-modeling

I am using google colab for SFA (stochastic frontier Analysis), It is giving me following error:

```
cannot import name 'StochasticFrontier' from 'frontier'
(/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/frontier/__init__.py)
```

I am not sure why this is the case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By frontier library, did you mean [this package](https://pypi.org/project/frontier/)? I don't think the class `StochasticFrontier` exist in the library